# AdminLTE with SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, adminlte

I'm using the sonata admin bundle for my admin panel, everything works fine.

I was able to create services and use sonata's version of form builder, now all that is left is to customise the dashboard, I want to use the AdminLTE layout for this, so how do I replace the sonata admin layout with my choice of layout.

The sonata blogs suggests that we use a different layout too, but the docs aren't too welcoming.

edit: I just saw the AdminLTE in the vendor folder of the sonata bundle, how would I activate it? it may not be the latest version of adminlte, how do I get the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You just have to play with configuration*

You download the AdminLTE version of your choice.

And after in sonata configuration file, you just have to override the *assets* and *javascript* entries.

[Here is the doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html#full-configuration-options)

Extract:

```
            # Prototype
            id:                   ~
templates:
    user_block:           'SonataAdminBundle:Core:user_block.html.twig'
    add_block:            'SonataAdminBundle:Core:add_block.html.twig'
    layout:               'SonataAdminBundle::standard_layout.html.twig'
    ajax:                 'SonataAdminBundle::ajax_layout.html.twig'
    dashboard:            'SonataAdminBundle:Core:dashboard.html.twig'
    search:               'SonataAdminBundle:Core:search.html.twig'
    list:                 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig'
    filter:               'SonataAdminBundle:Form:filter_admin_fields.html.twig'
    show:                 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show.html.twig'
    show_compare:         'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:show_compare.html.twig'
    edit:                 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:edit.html.twig'
    preview:              'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:preview.html.twig'
    history:              'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:history.html.twig'
    acl:                  'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:acl.html.twig'
    history_revision_timestamp:  'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:history_revision_timestamp.html.twig'
    action:               'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:action.html.twig'
    select:               'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__select.html.twig'
    list_block:           'SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_admin_list.html.twig'
    search_result_block:  'SonataAdminBundle:Block:block_search_result.html.twig'
    short_object_description:  'SonataAdminBundle:Helper:short-object-description.html.twig'
    delete:               'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:delete.html.twig'
    batch:                'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list__batch.html.twig'
    batch_confirmation:   'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:batch_confirmation.html.twig'
    inner_list_row:       'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_inner_row.html.twig'
    outer_list_rows_mosaic:  'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_outer_rows_mosaic.html.twig'
    outer_list_rows_list:  'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_outer_rows_list.html.twig'
    outer_list_rows_tree:  'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_outer_rows_tree.html.twig'
    base_list_field:      'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig'
    pager_links:          'SonataAdminBundle:Pager:links.html.twig'
    pager_results:        'SonataAdminBundle:Pager:results.html.twig'
    tab_menu_template:    'SonataAdminBundle:Core:tab_menu_template.html.twig'
    knp_menu_template:    'SonataAdminBundle:Menu:sonata_menu.html.twig'
assets:
    stylesheets:

        # Defaults:
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css
    --> - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css
    --> - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/admin-lte/dist/css/skins/skin-black.min.css
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/iCheck/skins/square/blue.css
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2/select2.css
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2-bootstrap-css/select2-bootstrap.min.css
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css
        - bundles/sonataadmin/css/styles.css
        - bundles/sonataadmin/css/layout.css
        - bundles/sonataadmin/css/tree.css
    javascripts:

        # Defaults:
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jquery.scrollTo/jquery.scrollTo.min.js
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/moment/min/moment.min.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jqueryui/ui/minified/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/jquery-form/jquery.form.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/jquery/jquery.confirmExit.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/x-editable/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js
        - bundles/sonatacore/vendor/select2/select2.min.js
     -->- bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/admin-lte/dist/js/app.min.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/iCheck/icheck.min.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/waypoints/lib/jquery.waypoints.min.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/vendor/waypoints/lib/shortcuts/sticky.min.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/Admin.js
        - bundles/sonataadmin/treeview.js
extensions:

    # Prototype
```

Comment: ok so if i wanted to change the layout of the panel, then i will have to replace `standard_layout.html.twig` inorder to change the html content inside it. that means i have to override all the twig blocks inside of the `standard_layout.html.twig` in my layout.html.twig ?

Comment: that's it. I've rewrite my own standard_layout and set the block where I wanted they should go. (in my case, the list filters are in control sidebar)